# macOS swift get first time App install date

Tags: swift, macos, app-store

How to get date of mac app purchased from App Store? (not related to In App Purchase just the date of  first time app downloaded)

I have tried below code but the date will be changed when user deleted the app folder from Library.

```
let urlToDocumentsFolder = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).last!
    //installDate is NSDate of install
    let installDate = (try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(urlToDocumentsFolder.path!)[NSFileCreationDate])
    print("This app was installed by the user on \(installDate)")
```

Comment: `originalPurchaseDate` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/apptransaction

Comment: @KinneyKare Not a duplicate question. The link sent by you is a solution for iOS not for macOS because user can manually delete app folder from ~Library.

Comment: @loremipsum originalPurchaseDate in only available for macOS 13+. Does any other property available for macOS 12 ?

Comment: You can get it from the receipt the “original way”